# Handle files from OnFileActivated()

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have problem with handling files passed to my application in `OnFileActivated()`. First, I've registred specific file extention in `Package.appminifest` of my application, so after tap into specific file my application starts and run OnFileActivated function.

In my case file is archive zipped with `System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive`, but I think it's not crutial here. Beggining of my function looks as follow:

```
    protected override async void OnFileActivated(FileActivatedEventArgs args) {
        base.OnFileActivated(args);

        var file = args.Files[0];
        using (var archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(file.Path)) {
        ...
```

As some of you can expect I get an error when I'm trying to access file in last line. I also tried different solutions as copying file into local folder and then access it, but also without luck.

**Question**
Is there any way to do such thing? Or maybe I'm doing it completely wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct answer:

```
    protected override async void OnFileActivated(FileActivatedEventArgs args) {
        base.OnFileActivated(args);

        var file = (StorageFile)args.Files[0];

        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())) {
        ...
```

I haven't noticed before that `ZipArchive` have constructor which takes stream as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Path` property will not be useful for a brokered file (such as you get from Activation). Use the constructor that takes a `Stream` instead.