# SharedStorageAccessManager is not accessible

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to use `SharedStorageAccessManager` in my Windows Phone 8.1 application to copy file passed to it by FileTypeAssociation. Such example is shown here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.phone.storage.sharedaccess.sharedstorageaccessmanager.copysharedfileasync(v=vs.105).aspx

The problem is I cannot find the way to reference it to my project. I've searched for `Windows.Phone.Storage.SharedAccess` but without success.

Is there anyone who know how can I add such lib?

Comment: Are you building a Silverlight app or a Universal app?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Universal app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are building a Universal app then you get a `StorageFile` directly from the activation arguments via the `Files` property and don't need to use the `SSAM`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Peter, I've expected that it's not available from Universal app (anyway, I haven't found any information which said so). But I've also checked the way which you've described before, as you can expect without success. Here is the link to my previous question which is related to described way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35734991/handle-files-from-onfileactivated Please, answer there if you're able to help. Regards